# What are key issues around publishing which websites block particular exit relays?

Tags: exit-relays, blocked-services, speed, website

The answer to [What common sites are known to be troublesome for Tor use?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/949/what-common-sites-are-known-to-be-troublesome-for-tor-use) is a "community wiki [that] will list commonly used websites known to be troublesome for Tor users." I have encountered such problems over the years with many websites, and I've seen many such complaints in the tor-talk mailing list, and elsewhere.

And so I've decided to test how well the top 50 websites work for Tor users, and to determine the pervasiveness of any blocking. I'm using a script that runs "torsocks midori -s http://foo.bar/" to snapshot sites, while using [exit_used.py](https://stem.torproject.org/tutorials/examples/exit_used.html) to determine exit relays used. Midori is configured send a Firefox user agent string.

An example for http://craigslist.org/ from preliminary results is [here](http://bayimg.com/lAoiMAAfL). It's possible that, given enough such information, someone might determine what server(s) I'm using. But that would arguably require collusion with entry guards. It wouldn't be problematic if the server(s) were tied to my mirimir persona.

Is there concern that unblocked exit relays will be blocked as a result? I don't think so. All of the exit relays in my example are obviously in [Atlas](https://atlas.torproject.org/), and they are all in the "DAN TOR" and "DAN TOREXIT" blacklists. But maybe I'm missing something.

What are other key issues around publishing which websites block particular exit relays?

Comment: This question has been up for a week, and has received no answers or substantive comments. Given that, it is apparently OK to publish information about website performance by exit relay. If there were serious issues, it's arguable that someone would have indicated so by now.

Comment: Do they really block specific exits or basically any exit?

Comment: I've been collecting data since mid June, but have only analyzed a few days worth. Preliminarily, it seems that each blocking website blocks a different set of exits, with some overlap.